# Classifying Google analytics data for local users

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a multi-user system and need to show google analytics data to user for content that they own. So, I need to classify, store and use analytics data related to my user id's.

What is the best way to do this, or is this possible via Google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve UID the data if you have not stored it, because the user id is hashed on the Google Analytics servers.

The easiest solution is store the user id in a custom var and extract them latter to be classified

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId'));
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Take care, this solution can be considered as a privacy policie violation, becuase it's on a gray area, use under your own risk